# How to use multiple UseCases that rely on the same repo so as to avoid multiple API calls?

Tags: android

I recently ran into a problem where I had to use multiple UseCases in different ViewModels and all these UseCases relied on the same repo to retrieve data via an HTTP API. So basically, the end result was that I was making 3 or 4 API requests in a span of few seconds, fetching the same data - pretty wasteful.

How would one solve this issue?

Two ways I can think of is via time dependent caching -

1. Fetch from a cache if an API is called multiple times in a given time period.
2. Such commonly accessed data can be fetched in a shared `ViewModel` and that is shared between the Main Activity and the Fragments.

Comment: what http/rest solution (library) are you using to access your api? have you checked if it has built in cache?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use Etag caching (if server supports it). With OkHttp it's almost out-of-the-box, you just need to configure the response cache.

If your server does not support the Etag, you still can add a cache interceptor with OkHttp, in which the cache control header is added by the app.

Another approach is to use Dropbox Store library or implement a custom cache mechanism in your app's data layer.

In some rare cases (if you use Kotlin), you could utilize the async, await, Deferred (to cache single API call) or Flow.stateIn.

I would not recommend using shared ViewModels, as it scales bad.